# Error Const TaggedMembers = mentions.users.map

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm probably not understanding but I would like someone to help me, I'm doing that if someone gives a mention to a user, read if they have afk set in the database so that they return it, I'm supposed to have already defined it in `Async execute (message)`

My code

```
const afkModel = require("../../Models/Afk");
const { Message } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: "messageCreate",
    async execute(message, client, guild) {
        if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

        let data = await  afkModel.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id, UserID: message.author.id })
        if(!data) return;
        if (data.Afk) {
            if(!data) return;
            data.Afk = false;
            data.save();
        }
        return;
    }
};

const taggedMembers = mentions.users.map(msg => msg.id);

if (taggedMembers.length > 0) {
    taggedMembers.forEach(m => {
        afkModel.findOne({ Guild: guild.id, UserID: m }, async (err, data) => {
            if (!data) return;
            if (data.Afk) {
                if(!data) return;
                message.reply(`This user is currently Afk. \nReason: ${data.Reason || "None provided."}`);
            }
            return;
        })
    })
}
```

My error

```
const taggedMembers = message.mentions.users.map(msg => msg.id);
                              ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joshuaacosta/Desktop/Sayu/Events/Messages/afk.js:20:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at loadEvents (/Users/joshuaacosta/Desktop/Sayu/Handlers/eventHandler.js:11:19)
    at /Users/joshuaacosta/Desktop/Sayu/index.js:41:5
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I would like to know if I am doing wrong and what should I add so that my command works when a user mentions another user and if he has afk he responds with a mention reply

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is different from what the error is stating as `message.mentions` has not been included in the code provided.

However, I presume you mean the line:

```js
const taggedMembers = mentions.users.map(msg => msg.id);
```

That snippet of code is outside of the `execute` function and therefore the variable `message` has not been defined in the scope.
To resolve this problem, move that code up into the function, as shows below:

```js
const afkModel = require("../../Models/Afk");
const { Message } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
  name: "messageCreate",
  async execute(message, client, guild) {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    let data = await afkModel.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id, UserID: message.author.id })
    if (!data) return;
    if (data.Afk) {
      if (!data) return;
      data.Afk = false;
      data.save();
      return;
    }

    const taggedMembers = message.mentions.users.map(msg => msg.id);

    if (taggedMembers.length > 0) {
      taggedMembers.forEach(m => {
        afkModel.findOne({ Guild: guild.id, UserID: m }, async (err, data) => {
          if (!data) return;
          if (data.Afk) {
            if (!data) return;
            return message.reply(`This user is currently Afk. \nReason: ${data.Reason || "None provided."}`);
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
};
```